# javascript to add source URL

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code in CEWP (content editor webpart) so after taking a survey user will be redirected to thank you page. the redirecting is not working. Am I missing something? (user able to take survey and newform.aspx never closes)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
 function PreSaveAction(){  
     var URL = location.pathname.replace("NewForm.aspx","/surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx");  
     if(GetUrlKeyValue("IsDlg")==="1"){  
         URL+="?IsDlg=1";  
     }  
     $("#aspnetForm").attr("action",location.pathname+"?Source="+URL);  
     return true;  
 }  
</script>
```

Comment: try to put alert box and see what you are getting

Comment: I added an alert before return true; and alert poped up.

Comment: try to put alert box after url variable set and see what your are getting in URL variable

Comment: i put the alert after the URL+="?IsDlg=1"; alert showed but got error on window.location(URL). (used IE dev tool)

Comment: alert(URL) looks like this on the browser  /surveys/Lists/TestSurvey//surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx?IsDlg=1

Answer (score 0):

Where's the redirect? Have you tried using `window.location(URL);` ?

Comment: I added Webpage error details
window.location(URL); or window.location = URL; right before return true; but getting following error 
Message: Object doesn't support this action

Answer (score 0):

Means you are getting double "/" in URL like this :

```
/surveys/Lists/TestSurvey//surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx?IsDlg=1
```

just remove starting / from below string

```
 /surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx
```